# Table on form in Python

Tags: python, forms, plot, header, row

I need to report some results on a table on a form in my application in Python. I found some general ways in internet but none of them sarisfied me. Do someone know how to show a table which be beautiful and efficient?

import plotly.graph_objects as go
....